# Excel Conditional Formatting based on Other Column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns in Excel as shown on the picture below.

[image]

I need to apply conditional formatting in this way:

if row in B column contain "1", the cell A on the same row should change its color. This needs to be applied only for the cell in A column, not whole row. Is there any option how to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Follow these steps and your problem will be solved ;)

1. Set your formula to `=$B2=1`
2. Select the fill color `Yellow`
3. Applies to `=$A$2:$A$7`
4. Once you click Apply, make sure your formula hasn't changed! (always happens to me)

[image]

[image]