# Conditional formatting based on multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a formula for the following, and can't figure out how to get all the conditions in there:

**Column A will be highlighted if:

G# is blank

AND/OR

H is today or before, WHEN J is blank**

to better illustrate, 
A is the client's name / 
G is date term's contract was signed /
H is date of next contract /
J is date contract on H was signed

I'm trying to get the client's name highlighted when the contract is due for signature, so if G is blank it should be highlighted, and if H is due and J is blank it should be highlighted.

And I would like to have this formula in the range A1:A137, with the G,H and J changing accordingly for each row.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Then add more details like what did you already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Conditional Formatting based on Other Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769277/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column)

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting column A and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=AND(A1<>"",OR(G1="",(AND(H1<>"",H1<=TODAY(),J1=""))))`

Select a background colour and click Done