# Keeping a conditional format on other cells even if value changes?

Tags: vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

There is probably a better way to do what this however for science, I have a cell which goes up and down and at certain break points I would like to change the conditional formatting on other cells if a certain number is ever hit I want to change the color of the cell and when it changes I still want that cell to be conditionally formatted. Is this possible using a formula to conditional format?

**Example**

Let's say 100 is one of my breakpoints.

When I hit 100 on cell A1, I want to change B2 to a green fill

Now let's say A1 Changes from 100 to 125 for whatever reason. I still want to keep the fill on B2

When trying the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Range("A1").value = 100 Then Range("B1").ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

I get this error

Run-Time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Is this what you're needing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769277/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column

Comment: @TheKirkwoods Using the example from the question you linked. I would want the cell to stay filled yellow even If I changed the 1. So basically if a 1  was ever in that cell I would want the cell that I formated to stay that way. I will try to add some more information once I am off work. Thank you

Comment: I think you need a VBA code: are you interested in conditional formatting solution only?

Comment: @user3598756 I would not be against it. :) I just recently started using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by placing this code in the relevant worksheet code pane (not in a standard module one):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If Target.Value = 100 Then Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
End Sub
```

You just have to change:

- colorindex to the wanted color one
- 100 to the needed breakpoint

Comment: When I try your code it works great, but I need to be more specific on which cells are the target. I would appricate it if you took a look at what I tried in my edit.