# Conditional formatting based on other column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table, that consists of 2 columns. I need to highlight values in first column, that are more or equal than 10% of the number in the second column.

I created additional row there, to clarify, but I can't use it in the formula, tho.

I need to use relative formula, since I am applying filter to these rows, so I need this all not to fall apart, if I am sorting table via filters.

[image: Look of the formatted table]

I have looked through this topic: [Excel Conditional Formatting based on Other Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769277/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column) , but I couldn't apply it. Or I failed at applying it.

I have tried to apply to the range (of `=$A$2:$A$8`)following formulas (in conditional formatting "Use a formula to determinate..."):

- `=$A2*100/$B2>=10`
- `=ADRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())*100/ADRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)>=10`

But none of them did the trick. Can someone help me with this one, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how conditional formatting works.

"I need to use relative formula ..."

No. You don't.

Conditional formatting, although I have never seen it stated anywhere, uses array-based formula. As such you describe the usage of the first instance in the (unfiltered) table, tell it the area of the table, and it will calculate the necessary *relative* addressing by itself. You do not tell it the relative addressing. Why it behaves like that, I can't tell you.

The formula will then maintain itself throughout any filtering or sorting you carry out. You do not need to account for filtering and sorting - provided, of course, you set everything up on the unfiltered table to begin with.

[image: Conditional Format]

[image: Page table]

You can see from the attached screenshots, simply using your formula of `=$A2*100/$B2>=10` and applying it to $A$2:$A$8 worked perfectly.