# Conditional formatting based on cell in different column but same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I apologize if this has been posted, but I haven't found a solution that works.

I have an excel sheet with a lot of data.

I want to make the cells in a certain column (column CG) turn purple if the value of a cell in a different column, but equal row is "no". For example, I want the cell in column CG row 140 to turn purple if the cell in column CS row 140 is no. I want this to happen for every cell in the column. I tried to set up a conditional formatting rule such that the rules applies to `=$CG$4:$CG$200` and for the formula I've tried `$CS=no`, `$CS="no"` `$CS4="no"` and `$CS4=no` with the formatting just being a purple highlight. I've tried hitting apply and ok, but nothing works.

I used these link to determine what to do for my rule. 
[Conditional formatting based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892583/conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column)
[Excel Conditional Formatting based on Other Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769277/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply *highlight the entire column "CG"* then open the CF dialog.

Select the option **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and type in the following formula:

```
=$CS1="no"
```

Then proceed to set your formatting, in your case, a purple fill.

---

> [image]